# How to create link to camera react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-camera

I found camera API in react-native: [react-native-camera](https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/rncamera)
This API allows having a camera inside of Components. But I don't like this, because by default it hasn't what has a camera app of the device. I want just to open the camera app of the device by clicking the button. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this NPM [react-native-image-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-picker)

```js
import ImagePicker from "react-native-image-picker";
export function showImagePickerDialog(darkMode) {
  return new Promise((resolve, _) => {

    const options = {
      title: 'Capture image',
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true,
        path: "images"
      },
      mediaType: 'photo',
      videoQuality: 'high',
      durationLimit: 10,
      maxWidth: 1000,
      maxHeight: 1000,
      allowsEditing: false,
      noData: true,
      quality: 0.8,
      tintColor: darkMode ? colors.colorWhite : colors.colorBlack,
    };
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, response => {

      if (response.didCancel || response.error) {
        resolve(false);
      }
      else {
        resolve(response);
      }
    })
  })
}
```